# Android icons and radio buttons not following day/night mode

Tags: android, androidx, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

After creating a very basic Settings AppCompatActivity and PreferenceFragmentCompat to change the day/night mode of my application, but the light theme doesn't seem to apply across the entire application. None of the icons in the rest of the application want to follow, and the radio buttons in the ListPreference dialog also seem to retain their original dark theme. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: System/Dark]

[image: Light]

SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settingsFrame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey);

            findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_theme)).setOnPreferenceChangeListener((preference, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue.toString().equals(getString(R.string.light))) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                } else if (newValue.toString().equals(getString(R.string.dark))) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_theme"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_day_24"
        android:title="@string/theme"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
        android:entries="@array/themes"
        android:entryValues="@array/themes"
        android:defaultValue="@string/system"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

ic_day_24.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M20,8.69L20,4h-4.69L12,0.69 8.69,4L4,4v4.69L0.69,12 4,15.31L4,20h4.69L12,23.31 15.31,20L20,20v-4.69L23.31,12 20,8.69zM12,18c-3.31,0 -6,-2.69 -6,-6s2.69,-6 6,-6 6,2.69 6,6 -2.69,6 -6,6zM12,8c-2.21,0 -4,1.79 -4,4s1.79,4 4,4 4,-1.79 4,-4 -1.79,-4 -4,-4z"/>
</vector>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.FloatingTimer" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/orange_normal</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/orange_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/blue_normal</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.FloatingTimer.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

theme.xml (night)

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.FloatingTimer" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/orange_normal</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/orange_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/blue_normal</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.FloatingTimer.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue_light">#FF6E9FCF</color>
    <color name="blue_normal">#FF3F7FBF</color>
    <color name="blue_dark">#FF2F6090</color>
    <color name="orange_light">#FFD97F3F</color>
    <color name="orange_normal">#FFCC5500</color>
    <color name="orange_dark">#FF9A4000</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="translucent_black">#CC000000</color>
    <color name="translucent_dark_gray">#CC333333</color>
    <color name="translucent_light_gray">#CCCCCCCC</color>
    <color name="translucent_white">#CCFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="translucent_overlay">@color/translucent_white</color>
    <color name="list_icon">@color/black</color>
</resources>
```

colors.xml (night)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="translucent_overlay">@color/translucent_dark_gray</color>3
    <color name="list_icon">@color/white</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Do you have a night version of colors.xml?

Comment: Added to the post. It should be noted I have also tried replacing every single color in the theme with `@color/orange_normal` to try and force visibility with no luck.

Comment: Looks like I shot myself in the foot, the colorControlNormal in the themes was affecting it. There are still many confusing aspects to how the dark and light mode are applied, like how the default action bar uses colorSurface and colorOnSurface in dark mode, but not in light mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I played myself by using `<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>` in my themes. After removing that the icon colors are correct now.